# Hook into the button clicked event when user clicks "new email" in outlook

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I need to find a solution for hooking in to the button clicked event when a user presses the "New email" button in Outlook.
Since I'm tampering with the email I don't want the email to be altered with unless it's on a new email, else the user will get prompted to save the email if they press escape.

Outlook 2010 VSTO AddIn is being used

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is latch onto the [`NewInspector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.inspectorsevents_event.newinspector.aspx) events from the `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Inspectors` property. If you check the [`MailItem.Sent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff868242.aspx) property (*from [`inspector.CurrentItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._inspector.currentitem.aspx)*), you can determine whether it is a new message or a received message.

What is the behavior you need to perform after latching onto the "New Message" action?

Comment: I need to change the sender of the email, if I do it when not detecting if its a new mail, i will tamper with the email, and when people press escape, they will be asked to save or discard the file, and they dont want this disturbing step :)

Comment: Im trying out your proposed solution now.. :)

Comment: Could you alter the message before sending (via [`MailItem.Send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event.send.aspx)) instead of during message creation?